# C# How to make a horizontal bar graph in the console app

Tags: c#

I need to make a horizontal bar graph that represent the occurrence of a number in my histogram dictionary.

I've tried messing around with Console.BackgroundColor however, this obviously just makes the lines background color blue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Speach;
            Speach = "I say to you today, my friends, so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream. " +
            "I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: We hold these truths to be self-evident: that all men are created equal. " +
            "I have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia the sons of former slaves and the sons of former slave owners will be able to sit down together at the table of brotherhood. " +
            "I have a dream that one day even the state of Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of freedom and justice. " +
            "I have a dream that my four little children will one day live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color of their skin but by the content of their character. " +
            "I have a dream today. I have a dream that one day, down in Alabama, with its vicious racists, with its governor having his lips dripping with the words of interposition and nullification; one day right there in Alabama, little black boys and black girls will be able to join hands with little white boys and white girls as sisters and brothers. " +
            "I have a dream today. I have a dream that one day every valley shall be exalted, every hill and mountain shall be made low, the rough places will be made plain, and the crooked places will be made straight, and the glory of the Lord shall be revealed, and all flesh shall see it together. " +
            "This is our hope. This is the faith that I go back to the South with. With this faith we will be able to hew out of the mountain of despair a stone of hope. With this faith we will be able to transform the jangling discords of our nation into a beautiful symphony of brotherhood. " +
            "With this faith we will be able to work together, to pray together, to struggle together, to go to jail together, to stand up for freedom together, knowing that we will be free one day. " +
            "This will be the day when all of God's children will be able to sing with a new meaning, My country, 'tis of thee, sweet land of liberty, of thee I sing. Land where my fathers died, land of the pilgrim's pride, from every mountainside, let freedom ring. " +
            "And if America is to be a great nation this must become true. So let freedom ring from the prodigious hilltops of New Hampshire. Let freedom ring from the mighty mountains of New York. Let freedom ring from the heightening Alleghenies of Pennsylvania! " +
            "Let freedom ring from the snowcapped Rockies of Colorado! Let freedom ring from the curvaceous slopes of California! But not only that; let freedom ring from Stone Mountain of Georgia! " +
            "Let freedom ring from Lookout Mountain of Tennessee! Let freedom ring from every hill and molehill of Mississippi. From every mountainside, let freedom ring. " +
            "And when this ha   ppens, when we allow freedom to ring, when we let it ring from every village and every hamlet, from every state and every city, we will be able to speed up that day when all of God's children, black men and white men, Jews and Gentiles, Protestants and Catholics, will be able to join hands and sing in the words of the old Negro spiritual, Free at last! free at last! thank God Almighty, we are free at last!";

            Console.WriteLine("Histogram");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1. Show Histogram");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Search for Word");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
            Console.WriteLine("Choice?");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            int choiceInt = Int32.Parse(choice);

            string[] SpeachSplit = Speach.Split();
            Dictionary<string, int> Historgram = new Dictionary<string, int>();


            if (choiceInt == 1)
            {    
                    var result = Speach.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                    .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x.ToLower(), "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", ""))
                                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

                ConsoleColor BarColor;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                BarColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

                foreach (var item in result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
                        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {BarColor}  {item.Value}");


            }
            else if(choiceInt == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Search word to find?");
                string wordSearch = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Historgram.TryGetValue(wordSearch, out int value))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{wordSearch}, value = {0}.", wordSearch);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{wordSearch} is not found.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I've tried looking up and reading many articles on how to do this but it seems very complex. I'm only a beginner to C# so I'm rather confused on how to make this horizontal bar ground. In the end it's meant to look something like this:
[image]

Simplified question: How do I make a horizontal bar graph that represent the occurrence of a number in my histogram dictionary?

Comment: Imagine that instead of coding you had to do this on *grid paper*, one square is one *character* length, and you have a list of words and numbers assoicated with them. What steps would you take? Now a complexity here is the *paper* is only *x units* wide, so how are you going to fit large bars on the paper?

Comment: @TheGeneral You would color one square for each time the word occurs, but how could you do that in a foreach loop?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ericlippert/probability/blob/episode30/Probability/Extensions.cs -- in this file I have methods that create both horizontal and vertical histograms in much the manner that you describe; that should give you some inspiration.

Comment: @EricLippert i'm not sure if that is inspiration, or just straight to blown mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you wouldn't use a `foreach`, you would use the old fashioned `for` *loop* and `Write` instead of `WriteLine`

```
...

// print x amount of something
for(var i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
   Console.Write("#"); 

// this creates the new line
Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
```

This is assuming it will fit in the console.

There are other issues here, you have right aligned words, and also you will need to learn how to color text in the console. However I'll leave these fun details up to you.

**Update**

```
public static void Print(List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> list)
{

   // get the max length of all the words so we can align
   var max = list.Max(x => x.Key.Length);

   foreach (var item in list)
   {
      // right align using PadLeft and max length
      Console.Write(item.Key.PadLeft(max));

      Console.Write(" ");

      // change color
      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;

      // Write the bars
      for (var i = 0; i < item.Value; i++)
         Console.Write("#");

      // change back
      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

      Console.Write(" ");
      // this creates the new line
      Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = Speach.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x.ToLower(), "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", ""))
                   .GroupBy(x => x)
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

Print(result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList());
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still learning and changing text's color is one of the things I'm currently learn. This does point me in the right direction however, so thank you!